# Pending Transactions in Electrum

Tags: transaction-fees, electrum, unconfirmed-transactions

I downloaded the new version of Electrum (4.0.2) and when I sent coin to my other wallet, I forgot to choose/add mining fees. Now the transaction is in Pending and has been for the last six hours. The coin is still showing in my Electrum wallet but I am not sure how -  or if - I should reverse it alt all and resend it with fees. What happens if I delete the pending transactions and try again? There are no confirmations showing for the transaction on blockchain.info but Electrum Transaction information says it has 10 confirmations.

Comment: You could try to RBF your transaction ? (Look for "add fees" or "replace transction" on the GUI)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check confirmations on blockstream.info
2. If unconfirmed, open the wallet where you had sent, spend those BTC by sending to another address in same wallet with a fee rate more than what others are paying. Check mempool here: https://mempool.observer
3. This is called child pays for parent transaction: https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/cpfp/
4. If unable to spend those unconfirmed BTC, there will be an option in Electrum settings which you need to enable